# How hard is it to switch from CakePHP to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp

The past 2 years, we have been building [a web application](http://kumutu.com) using CakePHP. So far we have quite enjoy CakePHP and think it is great. We evaluated Ruby on Rails before starting but decided on CakePHP because our team was more experienced with PHP / MySQL and it appeared more difficult/expensive to hire RoR developers.

Lately, we have been thinking about RoR because:

1. Many new highly successful web applications
   are built on RoR and most look *beautiful* and *simple* to use.
2. The user base, documentation,
   ability to find answers for RoR
   appears to be larger than CakePHP.
3. PHP comes in so many flavors that
   often developers we approach say
   they know CakePHP, but really they
   program PHP and don't stick to CakePHP
   conventions.
4. Ruby on Rails is created
   by a successful profit making
   business that relies on the codebase.
   Thus, giving us the assumption that
   RoR will improve faster than
   CakePHP.
5. Package management lets us
       believe that plugins are easier to
       install on RoR than CakePHP.

With this in mind. Our questions are:

1. How hard is it for a seasoned
   CakePHP programmer to switch from
   CakePHP to RoR?
2. How big a task would it be to
   rewrite a moderately sized CakePHP (conventions strictly followed)
   web application in RoR

Comment: this is a bit too subjective methinks. there's no definite way of measuring "how hard" it is to switch and it really depends on the how well the cakephp programmer knows MVC and Ruby syntax in general

Comment: The "beautiful" and "simple" qualities aren't due to Rails per se (unless you're looking at the source code), but rather good application design and javascript/css (which can be managed with any framework).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a very different beast than Ruby. PHP does not get even close to being as object oriented as Ruby is, and is a pretty big brain bender at first. That said, I think that a solid programmer with a good grasp of generic syntax should be able to fairly easily learn the new type of syntax.

```
$a = new A();
```

isn't that much different than

```
a = A.new
```

As far as Cake goes, vs Rails, that's another whole monster. Development with rails is fast. Very fast. But when you're converting a whole application on the fly, you'll need someone that can really break down its components, getting in to the nuts and bolts, quickly. So you can put together a skeleton for everyone to 'fill in'. At least, that's probably how I would approach it (though usually I would wait for a 'scheduled' re-write of an application to move to a completely new language).

Having some very experienced RoR developers on the team (at least during the interim) would probably significantly speed up the process, and get your team working as fast as possible. It may cost you a bit more to get up to speed, but it would greatly enhance productivity. And while I can't speak to the experience that duddle (different answer) has had, I know from experience that once you start writing in Ruby and get the gist of Rails, getting stuff implemented takes a lot less time than in PHP (YMMV). Though some of the ways that things are done in Rails flies in the face of conventional development practices (ActiveRecords, for instance, completely change the way that most people interact with databases).

Finally, the RoR community is massive compared to just about any other framework based community. Which is pretty slick in and of itself, and lets you really leverage a lot of different bits and pieces that just don't exist in the PHP community.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for "experienced RoR developers on the team".

Answer (score 2):

You might want to engage someone who is a Rails developer. This would be an important step to ease the transition process.

A good programmer will grasp Ruby fast, at least after reading important chapters of [Learning Ruby](http://www.amazon.de/Learning-Ruby-Michael-Fitzgerald/dp/0596529864/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301506395&sr=8-1) for example. Rails development, however, is very much about best practices. Reading through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) will get you far but it would be much easier to get started with somebody who has Rails project experience.

After learning / developing Rails part-time for 3 months, I lead a project with 5 students who did not know Ruby or Rails at all. Within 1 week, I could teach a developer the basic working of Rails and within 1-2 additional weeks, everyone could develop on his own. We built a production-ready mid-sized application within 3 months. It's not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit argumentative, but this is what i think :

1. You are making the right choice switching to Rails. I'm sure you will love it.
2. I won't lie though. Rails has a steep learning curve. It is difficult and requires lots of study.
3. Once you know how to do things with Rails, there is no faster way to develop web applications.
4. Ruby helps the programmer, Rails helps the programmer. A great fact.
5. I've been rewriting a browser game from PHP to Rails. After 2 weeks, about 60% of the work is done.

Comment: All good points. I love Rails, but many things in Rails lack good documentation. Also a lot of the examples you find in books only talk about simple cases, rarely do you find examples that go in-depth.